# blender 2.79 : Even after fresh install, no filmic color management options present

Tags: color-management, filmic-blender

Unfortunately I do not have the new option in the "Color Management" section of the "Scene" tab.
- The "Look" dropdown shows None only
- The "View" dropdown shows Default only

I chose Cycles as the renderer and tried both, CPU and CUDA.
I tried also the supported and experimental.
I wiped off all blender installs of my computer and did a fresh install.
No success.

Is there any hidden switch that enables these options?
Does anyone else have this issue?
Any hints on how to troubleshoot this?

System details:
 Windows 10 Pro (10.0.15063)
 Core i7 5820K,
 16GB RAM
 nvidia GeForce GTX 760

Comment: So if you expand those dropdown lists you see no other choice? Where did you get this 2.79? Did you uninstall or are you using a zip? Which system are you running this on?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOOD NEWS: SOLVED!

I figured it out: I am having three shortcuts that open blender. 1) Windows Startmenu, 2) Link on my desktop, 3) A shortcut on my ObjectDock Bar.
The latter is a Mac-style start bar [image] (by Stardock).
When I am starting blender from the ObjectDock shortcut, it seems to start blender in a different environment / with different permissions, where I am not aware what it is in detail (it is not the working directory).
- I started blender 10 times from there and had no filmic option available.
- I started blender 10 times from the desktop and startmenu and every time the options showed up as expected.
It was difficult to figure that out, because I randomly used one of these three shortcuts - so I randomly had the issue.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the problems too. So I deleted the blender short cut from my tast bar and dest top and went to computer/c drive/users/users(name)/my document/blender files. That where I found blender 2.9. Every time you download a new blender software, get rid of the old short cuts and make a new one. Thanks for your help bud.